# Como adicionar uma moldura a uma imagem?(Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, imagem

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em que preciso adicionar uma moldura a uma imagem.Vou adicionar a imagem uma moldura como essa abaixo e vou retornar a imagem editada. Como posso fazer isso?
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O quê você já tentou fazer? Em que parte do código está com dúvida?

Comment: use duas imageview dentro de um relative layout